# How to extract the public key algorithm from a String public key?

Tags: java, public-key

I have a String public key and I'm trying to convert it to Java PublicKey object using the code below, however I don't know the algorithm that was used to generate this public key. Is there anyway to extract the algorithm name from the String public key?

```
 String stringPubKey = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEmRk7MSZQCX2u4UIQgVzma1JEo3yASVafls/5nw/V9T6e5EbsK64MM0KhsPH9aK/aElRt1+Rxtd1AsHVvsQJjKw==";
 byte[] publicBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringPubKey);
 X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
 KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithmName);
 PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firat an aside: what you have is *one* 'String' (textual) representation of a publickey, specifically the base64 encoding of an ASN.1 structure SubjectPublicKeyInfo defined in X.509 and PKIX, and used by default in Java crypto as noted in the doc for [`X509EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) but explained more fully in [`Key`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html). There are many other 'string' representations of publickeys which are quite different, and not so easily usable in Java.

Java actually has classes for this and related structures -- and uses them when processing an X.509 *certificate* which *includes* SPKI -- but they are internal and undocumented, and while in years past it was possible to just call internal classes Java (Oracle) is now on a massive effort to progressively make this more difficult or impossible, so I can't recommend it.

**If you can use third-party code specifically [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org)** it is easy. The closest way to what you asked for is to parse the SPKI and get the algorithm 'name' from it -- but this is in the form of an ASN.1 Object Identifier aka OID, not the name Java normally uses. *If* you use the BouncyCastle *provider* (`bcprov*.jar`) for the `KeyFactory` call, it has an alias mapping for this OID to the normal name:

```
    String stringPubKey = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEmRk7MSZQCX2u4UIQgVzma1JEo3yASVafls/5nw/V9T6e5EbsK64MM0KhsPH9aK/aElRt1+Rxtd1AsHVvsQJjKw==";
    byte[] publicBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringPubKey);
    
    String oid = org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(publicBytes)
            .getAlgorithm().getAlgorithm().toString(); /* yes, two different .getAlgorithm() ! */
    PublicKey pk = KeyFactory.getInstance(oid, new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())
            .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes));
    System.out.println(oid + " -> " + pk.getAlgorithm());
```

However, if you use the `bcpkix*.jar` library (which depends on bcprov being available but not necessarily registered) it handles the OID-name mapping with *any* provider (like the normal SunEC) and manages the KeyFactory for you in one step:

```
    // setup as above
    /*PublicKey*/ pk = new org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPublicKey(
            org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(publicBytes));
    System.out.println(pk.getAlgorithm());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it but I think it is the keyspec you give that has the algorithm. See getAlgorithm() method here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/security/KeyFactory.html

Also here (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#KeyFactoryEx) I have seen this:

> Algorithm Parameters Classes Like Keys and Keyspecs, an algorithm's initialization parameters are represented by either
> AlgorithmParameters or AlgorithmParameterSpecs. Depending on the use
> situation, algorithms can use the parameters directly, or the
> parameters might need to be converted into a more portable format for
> transmission or storage.
>
> A transparent representation of a set of parameters (via
> AlgorithmParameterSpec) means that you can access each parameter value
> in the set individually. You can access these values through one of
> the get methods defined in the corresponding specification class
> (e.g., DSAParameterSpec defines getP, getQ, and getG methods, to
> access p, q, and g, respectively).
>
> In contrast, the AlgorithmParameters class supplies an opaque
> representation, in which you have no direct access to the parameter
> fields. You can only get the name of the algorithm associated with the
> parameter set (via getAlgorithm) and some kind of encoding for the
> parameter set (via getEncoded).